# Proper structure for C++ project & libs

Tags: c++, oop, compilation, g++

I'm starting to write a data processing library of mine and quite confused about building the proper structure of project and libraries.

Say, I'd like to have a set of functions stored in myfunclib library. My current set up (taken from multiple recommendations online) looks like this:

myproj/include/myfunclib.h - class declaration
myproj/include/myfunclib.cpp - class functionality
myproj/src/functest.cpp - test file to check functions

Firstly, it feels like this is a proper set up in case I use myfunc only for myproj project, but say I want to reuse it - then I'd need to specify it's path in each of cpp files using it or store multiple copies of it.

Secondly, compilation is a bit bulky in such case:

```
g++ -I include include/myfunclib.cpp src/functest.cpp
```

Is it a normal practice to type all that stuff every time? What if I have many custom libraries I need? Is there a way to store them all separately, simply include as 'myfunclib.h' and not worry about recompiling etc?

Comment: Google `make` and `Makefile`.

Comment: Most people use `make` or an IDE. With an IDE, you can usually specify common search paths, but need to choose the libraries on a per-project basis.

Comment: I'm trying to stick with vim and command line. Will look up 'make', thanks. What about directory structure?

Comment: To make a library especially a good library is much more difficult than to make a program similar size. You probably should write some programs first.

Comment: In case you're curious where to find documentation on gnu make, [it can be found here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Comment: Thanks, Slava, I wrote lots of programs before, but I used Java and Eclipse which sort of figures everything for yourself without much thought. I'm merely trying to transfer all that to c++.

Comment: Besides the fact that you should start using some tool for the builds (check Makefile for the traditional one, CMake, SCONS,... for newer --not necessarily better approaches), I would reconsider separating the header from the implementation files. I tend to prefer having both together during editing, and then for libraries, having a target that copies the result of the compilation and the headers to a different location. Having the files together is simpler for my editing, and it keeps the version that other parts of the project use separate to avoid breaking them while editing.

Comment: @sashkello you won't get very far this way...  What's wrong with sticking with the IDE you already know (Eclipse) and it's C++ plugin?

Comment: Paul, I'm here not to discuss why I'm doing what I'm doing, but after an answer to specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a makefile to handle all of your dependencies and building your code. Google the syntax it's pretty simple. then you can just say "make" on the command line and it will build everything for you.

here's a good tutorial
http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Answer (score 0):

some things that bit me originally,

remember that templated classes should only be included, what is generally the source implementation should not be built like normal class implementations into object files, so generally i put my whole template implementation within the include directory

i keep include and source files separate, by source files i mean code (definitions) that needs to be compiled into object files for linking, and includes are all the declarations, inline functions, etc it just seems to make more sense to me

sometimes i'll have a header file that includes all relevant headers for a specific module, and in turn perhaps a header file higher up that includes all main headers for modules i am using

also as said in the comments, you need to introduce yourself to some build tools, and get comfortable with them, these will help you track dependencies within your project, and in most cases avoid rebuilding an entire project when only a subset of dependencies have changed (this can be a pain to get right in the beginning but is worthwhile learning, if you use make and g++ there is a way to get this working with g++ -MM ... not sure how well it works for all cases ), i know that the way i organized my projects changed drastically the more i learnt about the build process, and the more complex my projects became (and the more flaws i had to fix )

this is how i generally keep my a project directory structure when starting

```
build - where all the built files will be stored
app - these are the main apps (can also be split into include/src)
include - includes files
src - src files (compiled into objects and then linked with main compiled app)
lib - any libs (usually 3rdparty libs , if any my src is compiled into a library it usually ends up in build/lib/target/... )
```

hope some of this helps

Comment: one more thing to add, the best reason to keep source and include files separate, if you are going to share your project as a library, once the library is built, the user will both need to link to the library and include your header files to use it, quite often this means copying these files to another location, so having your includes bundled like that does make it simpler